# Change the content of the current executable. Is it possible?

Tags: locking, byte, range, execution, disassembly

I have listen, that you may use such functions like `LockBytes()/UnlockBytes()` from WinAPI (don't know about the exact name in *nix alternative) for such the aims.

I'm interested: "Is it possible to change the content of some *.exe during its execution?"

I think, it's rahter impossible due threading locker-models like: Semaphore, Spinlock and other...

But **does some way exist**?

Maybe, if to embded the resources in the EXE and make it locked for the prepared own threading model and at the execution and then unlock the region of the bytes of it and change the value you need.

I'm interested in this question because of the following reasons:

- Security online checks. I want to change some values, which will be used for the online key checker (like writting checksums and sessions to such bytes-region and check it online, etc...)
- I don't want to write to the another file or to the registry or smth else, because I want to pass UAC/chmod from preventing to access filesystem space or system registry.

PS

I don't want to make viruses, just good protection for my own program from the hacking the trial-checks/disassemling.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution:

1. Move the bulk of code you want to protect into your own DLL instead of keeping it in EXE;
2. In the main executable, read the DLL into memory and use https://github.com/fancycode/MemoryModule to load it.

Then the DLL won't be locked, and you can update its resources as you want (if you have permissions).

The above is for Windows systems, and MemoryModule is for PE format. On unix, two things are different:

1. You can rename and replace an executable while it's running, so there's no need to write into the same file, BUT
2. No one in his right mind will install the program system-wide with a permissions enabling ordinary users to write the program's executable file or directory (btw, is it that different on Windows? You seem to be sure that UAC won't prevent you from writing your own executable if you could do it, but it might not be so).

Comment: it's the main problem! I want to update resources with not having the permissions. Maybe there is a way: 1). Make a driver, which runs like other *.sys drivers in Native Mode then exchaning messages via csrss.exe between usermode program and the driver to change the content (driver rewrites the app program content).

Comment: How come you can require a driver to be installed (and users will agree), but you can't have a single world-writable file nearby your program because UAC complains? Anyway, I doubt that it's possible. With your willingness to go low-level, maybe: e.g. you can open a block device, locate your program's blocks on NTFS somehow and modify them on disk, but you need an awful lot of permissions to do it anyway.

Comment: notice please! User will install driver only once. But programm will make checks etc many times. That's first difference. Admins may in future change permissions and program may stop to work, but with scheme of driver it will protect from admins action of blocikg the access for the program. That's one more else detail why I'm asking for.